# Posso passar uma string, que não esteja armazenada previamente em um vetor, como parâmetro para um função?

Tags: c, string, funções, parâmetros

Escrevi essa função para retirar os caracteres ***não*** repetidos de uma string qualquer em c:

```
char *repeticoes(char *s){
    int i=0, j, cont=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(s);j++)
            if(s[j]==s[i] & j!=i)
                break;
        if(j==strlen(s))
            for(j=i;j<strlen(s);j++)
                s[j]=s[j+1];
        else
            i++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Quando passo para ela como parâmetro um vetor s, `s[20]="felicidade"`, tenho a saída esperada que seria `"eiidde"`, mas quando passo como parâmetro um vetor `*s="felicidade"` ou simplesmente `"felicidade"` e mando compilar, o programa parece não responder.

Funciona normalmente:

```
int main(void){
    char s[20]="felicidade";    

    printf("%s",repeticoes(s));
}
```

não funcionam:

```
int main(void){
    char *s="felicidade";   

    printf("%s",repeticoes(s));
}
```

```
int main(void){
    printf("%s",repeticoes("felicidade"));
}
```

Comment: é porque `*s` é um ponteiro na qual você deve "apontar" para um posição da memoria, quando você passa diretamente "felicidade" isto não esta alocado na memoria, ou seja não tem um posição ainda.